# Command-line input causes SyntaxError

Tags: python, input, command-line, python-2.x

I have this code:

```
# Compare phone number  
phone_pattern = '^\d{3} ?\d{3}-\d{4}$'

phoneNumber = str(input("Please enter a phone number: "))

if re.search(phone_pattern, "258 494-3929"):  
    print "Pattern matches"
else:  
    print "Pattern doesn't match!"
```

When I try to type the phone number in response to the `input` prompt, I get an error:

```
Please enter a phone number: 258 494-3929  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
   File "pattern_match.py", line 16, in <module>  
     phoneNumber = str(input("Please enter a phone number: "))  
   File "<string>", line 1  
     258 494-3929  
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you storing it as a string or raw?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `raw_input` instead of `input`, and you don't have to call `str`, because this function returns a string itself:

```
phoneNumber = raw_input("Please enter a phone number: ")
```

Answer (score 10):

In Python version 2.x, input() does two things:

1. Reads a string of data. (You want this.)
2. Then it evaluates the string of data as if it were a Python expression. (This part is causing the error.)

The function raw_input() is better in this situation because it does #1 above but not #2.

If you change:

```
input("Please enter a phone number: ")
```

to read:

```
raw_input("Please enter a phone number: ")
```

you'll eliminate the error of the phone number not being a valid Python expression.

The input() function has tripped up so many people learning Python that starting with Python versions 3.x, the designers of the language removed the extra evaluation step.  This makes input() in versions 3.x behave the same as raw_input() in versions 2.x.

See also [a helpful wikibooks article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_output).

Comment: calling `str()` is not necessary after calling `raw_input()` (unless this was a cut-n-paste error) :-)

your other point is quite valid: use `raw_input()` in Python 2 and `input()` in Python 3... the name was changed but the function remains the same. `input()` in Python 2 causes problems as described by the OP, hence the reason why it's being/been removed from the language altogether (in Python 3 that is)

Comment: It's true the `str()` call is superfluous, as was mentioned in some of the other answers.  However, it's not causing the SyntaxError.

Answer (score 4):

The input() function actually *evaluates* the input that's typed into it:

```
>>> print str(input("input: "))
input: 258238
258238
>>> print str(input("input: "))
input: 3**3 + 4
31
```

It's trying to evaluate '258 494-3929' which is invalid Python.

Use `sys.stdin.readline().strip()` to do your read.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` calls `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, so you want `phoneNumber = raw_input("Please enter a phone number: ").strip()`

See also http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input and http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input