# Read a data from terminal within a script

Tags: python

I wanted to read a variable from terminal by running a script.
This is my script.py:

```
while True:
  value = input('enter text: ')
  if value == 'stop':
    print('bye-bye')
    break
  else:
    print('continue!')
```

However, when I ran `python script.py`, something weird happened.
If i entered int-data (for instance 1,2,3), there was no problem.
If i entered 'stop', I just got an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: i run this, and it works with `stop`

Comment: What is the full error traceback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command-line input causes SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589309/command-line-input-causes-syntaxerror) ---- You're running python 2 so you need `raw_input`. This is python 3 code, where `raw_input` was replaced by `input`.

Comment: Thank you, but really? i can't. Do you know how to post a picture in the comment?

Comment: input text:'stop'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    value = input('input text:')
  File "<string>", line 1
    'stop'
      ^

Comment: Which version of python are you using ?

Comment: @harry you can edit your question to add new information. Don't post a picture of the traceback. Copy, paste and format it. -- anyway, this is solved.

Comment: @FHTMitchell, @pLOPeGG; Thanks, but i am using Python 3...

Comment: @Harry What is the result of `import sys; print(sys.version)` at the top of your script?

Comment: @FHTMitchell 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]. Ah, i changed to raw_input, but i still get the error..

Comment: @Harry So it's python 2.7.12, not python 3... You still get the exact same error with `raw_input`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell, yep...But i noticed that if i enter ''stop, the second ' would be eaten...

Comment: @Harry Can you please edit your original post with the error you get when using `raw_input`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell, i was using a german keyboard. But after i changed to the english one. it was solved...So basically, i have to use the english keyboard, right?

Comment: err unless you're inputting unicode characters like ß, ä, ö, ü that shouldn't matter. My suggestion is you should upgrade to python 3, use your original code and not care about unicode.

Comment: @FHTMitchell, thanks for your suggestions! Thanks! It works.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Python2. In Python2 `input()` returns an `int`, for having a `string` you should use `raw_input()`:

```
while True:
  value = raw_input('enter text: ')
  if value == 'stop':
    print('bye-bye')
    break
  else:
    print('continue!')
```

Do not use `input()` in Python2 since it actually evaluates the input, and it can be dangerous. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) for the difference from Python3 and Python2 `input()`.

When you change to `raw_input()`, be sure to save before calling the script

Comment: Accept the Answer that helped you, or create a new one and accept that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def console(input_):
    input_ = input(r'Enter text: ')
    if input_ == str(r'stop'):
        return ("BYE BYE")
    else:
        input_ = input('continue')
    console(input_)

console(input)
```

Works fine on python3.