# Invalid syntax from my variable input in python

Tags: python, function, input, ip

I'm trying to code a program that give IPs information. When I try to get the IP by `input` and run it appears `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`it just let me put strings on it. Here is my code:

```
 def _get_ip():
    ip = ''

    _get_ = input('What\'s the IP?: {}'.format(ip))

_get_ip()
```

Comment: Probably your indentation.

Comment: If none of these suggestions fix your problem, then show the actual run of the program.

Comment: Also, don't name a variable with leading and trailing underscores :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command-line input causes SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589309/command-line-input-causes-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, `input` tries to evaluate the string you enter.  Use `raw_input` instead.